# getting adb for samsung galaxy nexus to work

Tags: android, adb, galaxy-nexus

I'm trying to debug my application on my brand new Galaxy Nexus.
I have done the following:

Drivers:
  installed the Galaxy driver 
  installed the Galaxy Nexus driver
(one can see this in the device manager, Galaxy under "Other Devices", Galaxy Nexus under "Portable Devices.")

I have also, on the phone, gone into settings->developer options and turned USB Debugging ON.
I have also added the debug-mod option to my application's manifest.

now I have navigated in my command prompt to the directory..
...\Android\android.sdk\platform-tools\
and I now try to do the command

adb devices.

The result is: 
"List of devices attached"

And then a blank line.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: I will keep this in mind.  However, for the most part, my questions have not been answered in a satisfactory manner :)

Comment: @Ethan That may be, but are you sure the answer below didn't solve it? It did for me.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue and the steps I took to get it to work were as follows:

1. Disconnect the phone from PC.
2. Uninstall the existing driver ("SAMSUNG USB Drivers for Mobile Phones" in Add or Remove Programs).
3. Restart PC.
4. Download and install the drivers: http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I515MSAVZW (Manuals & Downloads tab, Software)
5. Turn on USB Debugging in phone settings.
6. Connect phone to PC.

You should see it install correctly, and in Device Manager you need to see Android Phone -> SAMSUNG Android ADB Interface. If you don't see that, either the drivers aren't installed correctly or the phone isn't connected correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the official OEM USB driver from here:

http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I515MSAVZW

The link from the OEM USB Drivers page, on the Android developers site, will bring you here. Install it, and all should work well!

Hope it helps.

Comment: I cannot find the driver on this link - only leads to downloading the manual.

Comment: Scrap that, I had failed to notice the 'Software' tab. Sorry.